# In SQLite, transpose query results to count values

Tags: sql, sqlite

**Background**

I have a SQLite table, `d`, that looks like this:

```
+--+---+------------+------------+
|id|sex|event_type_1|event_type_2|
+--+---+------------+------------+
|a |m  |1           |1           |
|b |f  |0           |1           |
|c |f  |1           |0           |
|d |m  |0           |1           |
+--+---+------------+------------+
```

**The Problem**

I'm trying to write a query that yields the following summary of counts of `event_type_1` and `event_type_2` cut (grouped?) by `sex`:

```
+-------------+-----+-----+
|             |  m  |  f  |
+-------------+-----+-----+
|event_type_1 |  1  |  1  |
+-------------+-----+-----+
|event_type_2 |  2  |  1  |
+-------------+-----+-----+
```

This seems to involve some kind of transposition of the 2 `event_type` columns into rows of the query result that I'm not familiar with as a novice SQL user.

**What I've tried**

I've so far come up with the following query:

```
SELECT event_type_1, event_type_2, count(sex)
FROM d
group by event_type_1, event_type_2
```

But that only gives me this:

```
+------------+------------+-----+
|event_type_1|event_type_2|count|
+------------+------------+-----+
|1           |1           |1    |
|1           |0           |1    |
|0           |1           |2    |
+------------+------------+-----+
```

In another similar post, I asked how to do this in PostgreSQL, and was given an answer by Gordon Linoff that worked:

```
select v.which,
       count(*) filter (where d.sex = 'm') as m,
       count(*) filter (where d.sex = 'f') as f
from d cross join lateral
     (values (d.event_type_2, 'event_type_2'),
             (d.event_type_1, 'event_type_1')
     ) v(val, which)
where v.val = 1
group by v.which", drv = "SQLite")
```

My needs have changed, though, and I need to do this in SQLite. I've been trying to adapt this code to SQLite using lateral joins, but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'event_type_1' AS event_type, SUM(sex='m') AS m, SUM(sex='f') AS f FROM d WHERE event_type_1
UNION
SELECT 'event_type_2' AS event_type, SUM(sex='m') AS m, SUM(sex='f') AS f FROM d WHERE event_type_2
```

Or, if you can transpose the rows/columns in your calling programming language instead of doing it in SQL, you can just use:

```
SELECT sex, SUM(event_type_1), SUM(event_type_2) FROM d GROUP BY sex
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite there are various methods.  One uses a `cross join`:

```
select which,
       sum(sex = 'm') as m,
       sum(sex = 'f') as f
from d cross join
     (select 'event_type_1' as which union all select 'event_type_2' as which) v
group by which;
```

The advantage of using `CROSS JOIN` is that the original table is scanned only once.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Linoff. Might there be a dangling parenthesis somewhere? Getting an error `near "(": syntax error`. Messing with it myself but can't find it. Here's a db<>fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8fd58668eff3a161d2188be36ab5907f

Comment: @logjammin . . . The `values` clause may not be available in the version of SQLite that you are using.

Comment: Tip: Unlike other dialects of SQL (e.g., Microsoft's), SQLite lets you freely mix numeric and Boolean values.  So you can just write `SUM(sex = 'm')` and `SUM(sex = 'f')` without the `case` expressions.